# OpenLayers 6.12 can't load GML 3.1.1 features from EPSG:32620 and WFS 2.0.0

Tags: openlayers, gml

With OpenLayers 6.12, I cannot visualize a layer concerning Martinique EPSG:32620.

As I have no error I don't know if it comes from this projection or from the GML which would not be compatible.
I know however that there is a result for [https://datacarto.geomartinique.fr/wfs?version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=ms:pref_chlordecone_analyse_sol_v2_s_972&outputFormat=gml3&SRSNAME=EPSG:32620&bbox=-6800151.831794434,1640142.7893100686,-6780421.9682055665,1647728.6106899313,EPSG:3857](https://datacarto.geomartinique.fr/wfs?version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=ms:pref_chlordecone_analyse_sol_v2_s_972&outputFormat=gml3&SRSNAME=EPSG:32620&bbox=-6800151.831794434,1640142%20.7893100686,-6780421.9682055665,1647728.6106899313%20,EPSG:3857)

but the features remain hopelessly empty.
What to do?

My code :

```
var chlorodeconeMartiniqueSource = new ol.source.Vector({
                        format: new ol.format.WFS(),
                        loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
                            var proj = projection.getCode();
                            var url = 'https://datacarto.geomartinique.fr/wfs?version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ms:pref_chlordecone_analyse_sol_v2_s_972&outputFormat=gml3&SRSNAME=EPSG:32620&' + 'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',' + 'EPSG:3857'
                            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                            xhr.open('GET', url);
                            xhr.onload = function() {
                                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                                    console.log('url',url)
                                    var features = chlorodeconeMartiniqueSource.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText, { //chlorodeconeMartiniqueSource.getFormat()
                                        dataProjection: 'EPSG:32620', 
                                        featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
                                    })
                                chlorodeconeMartiniqueSource.addFeatures(features)
                                console.log('xhr.response',xhr.responseText)
                                console.log('features',features)
                                console.log('chlorodeconeMartiniqueSource',chlorodeconeMartiniqueSource)
                                }
                                }
                                xhr.send();
                                },
                                strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
                                });
```

Comment: Did you define/register projection `EPSG:32620` with proj4? (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj_proj4.html#.register)?

Comment: Yes i try 
proj4.defs("EPSG:32620" ,"+proj=utm +zone=20 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs");
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ol.format.WFS()` defaults to version 1.1.0 with GML3

Either use `version=1.1.0` in your url to reflect that

or you will need to specify both the WFS and GML version

```
ol.format.WFS({version: '2.0.0', gmlFormat: new ol.format.GML3()})
```

since version 2.0.0 will expect GML3.2 unless another version is specified

https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-wfs-forked-bjz6rf?file=/main.js